# CircleCi .yml Ruby without Rails test path in the run command

Tags: ruby, sinatra, circleci

I am trying to find the syntax to call my test file. I am not using rails/rake. Everything I am finding is using rails. That is not an option for me at this point.

Does CircleCi even work with a sinatra app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `.circleci` folder on your project's root directory and place `config.yml` that contain circleci configuration as describe at [circleci for ruby](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-ruby/) (thought it describe for rails project, it's same for sinatra). [Here](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-ruby-sinatra) is sinatra example project that use circleci.

Comment: If I set it up like a rails .yml, will I need rspec?
Is there not a way to call the test file?